# postfix. routing outgoing mails by message-id

Tags: postfix

I know there is a **sender_dependent_default_transport_maps** setting in Postfix to route outgoing mails through different relays based on the **sender**

Is such routing based on **message-id** possible?
If so, how?

Comment: What is the realistic use case? I mean, what real world problem are you trying to solve this way?

Comment: Message-I’d value is just a string that is expected to be globally unique. The fact that it contains domain names and formatt d like an email address means nothing and you should not try to rely on any specific format.